# What are the available methods in C++ std library, where can I see/read them?

Tags: c++

Where can I see all the available methods in std library ? Since, I can include vector,algorithm in my program, can I see header/source files for this library to see how it is implemented ?

eg. I know we can use push_back() method in vector, but where can I see all the methods for vector, and similarly for others library ?

Is there any documentation for it ?

I am using ubuntu, if this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check the source out, have a look into **/usr/include/c++/x.x/vector**

you'll probable need to redirect your research in this directory (depeding on the class you are looking at): /usr/include/c++/x.x/**bits**

For instance, **string** class is a typedef, and the underlying type is **basic_string** you will find in /usr/include/c++/x.x/**bits/basic_string**

Answer (score 3):

Linux developers often use [http://www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/) as documentation source. But to completely understand how to work with STL I recommend to read [*Effective STL*](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html) by Scott Meyers.

One more way is to use man pages. Install documentation with:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6-4.2-doc
```

After that you'll be able to read documentation with command `man`:

```
man std::vector
```

Comment: Very good tip! I've rushed on my ubuntu box to install it, the 6.4.3 package version does not seems to contain any man files ... ? Prefer the 6.4.2 version as mentioned by Jla3ep (I'll try later..)

Answer (score 3):

[Dinkumware](http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/default.aspx) reference.

[STL reference](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/) from SGI.

Comment: Also the C++ standard, available from bookshops.

Answer (score 2):

This web site has a lot of the things you're looking for : [C++ STL Vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)

There are a lot of books and web sites on the subject. Googling for STD or STL library will give you a world of links

Here is a list of [containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/)

Here is a list of [algorithms](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/)

Answer (score 2):

[CPP Reference](http://www.cppreference.com/)

other references might be useful depending on the platform you're implementing ( like [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bstk3k5.aspx) for Windows )

Comment: MSDN's reference is fine regardless of which platform you're working on. It describes the library according to spec, and clearly marks Microsoft-specific extensions. And it's a lot more complete and thorough than cppreference.com in my experience

Comment: I didn't say it isn't complete - this is why I've put it there - but it contains also the MS-specific additions (which are not standard and not portable - either between platforms or even between compilers on the same platform ).

Answer (score 2):

Alexander Stepanov created the STL while employed at HP. [This](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/) is the original documentation of his work, now hosted at Sgi, and probably the most used reference.